# Port forwarding is not working on CISCO router

Tags: cisco, openvpn, nat, port-forwarding

I have installed [Open VPN Access server](https://docs.openvpn.net/getting-started/deploying-the-access-server-appliance-on-vmware-esxi/) on a ESXI server.

To access it from outside , I have added port forwarding to CISCO router using following command.

```
#conf t
#ip nat inside source static tcp 10.201.102.163 443 <MY_EXTERNAL_IP> 443
#ip nat inside source static udp 10.201.102.163 443 <MY_EXTERNAL_IP> 443
```

There were no errors or any messages after executing these commands.

But when I navigate to `https://<MY_EXTERNAL_IP>`, I am not able to reach access server?

**Edit**
Result of  `sh ip access-list`

```
## are intentional 

Extended IP access list 100
    10 permit ip 10.##.102.0 0.0.0.255 any
    20 permit ip 10.##.103.0 0.0.0.255 any
Extended IP access list 101
    10 deny ip 10.##.103.0 0.0.0.255 10.##.102.0 0.0.0.255 (1495005761 matches)
    20 permit ip 10.##.103.0 0.0.0.255 any (50722431 matches)
Extended IP access list 102
    10 permit ip 10.1.45.0 0.0.0.255 any (1015320 matches)
    20 permit ip 10.1.40.0 0.0.0.255 any (41479 matches)
Extended IP access list 110
    10 permit ip 10.##.103.0 0.0.0.255 10.##.102.0 0.0.0.255 (1498725218 matches)
Extended IP access list 199
    10 permit tcp any host 1##.9.54.227 range 49000 49500 (12909 matches)
```

Comment: Have you created ACEs to permit the traffic?

Comment: I have no idea about ACEs?

Comment: ACE is access control entry. You need to have a NAT rule to translate the IP address from the internal to the external (which you showed us). You also need an ACE that says traffic from the outside (you can restrict this to specific IP addresses or networks) are allowed to reach your local server.

Comment: I just run the config command showed here. How do I check if there are already ACE applied?

Comment: Please run and share the results for sh ip access-list

Comment: @user5870571, Update question with result for  sh ip access-list

Comment: The host gateway is set ?

Comment: @yagmoth555, How do I check ? I am completely new to networking , though have fare bit of programming experience.

Comment: What does the output of #term mon
#debug ip nat detailed show?

Answer (score 0):

Have you assigned the inside and outside designations to the relevant interfaces ?

```
Router# int G0/0
Router# ip address <private-ip> <mask>
Router# ip nat inside
```

and

```
Router# int G0/1
Router# ip address <public ip> <mask>
Router# ip nat outside
```

Comment: @ What would be the mask?

Comment: The subnet mask... it indicates which portion of the address is the network and which is the host. You should be able to get details of this by using :  #show interfaces